# ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater и mixing versions libs can lead to runtime crashes

Tags: android

Ошибка:

```
com.google.android.gms.ui I/AppCompatDelegate: Failed to instantiate custom view inflater android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater. Falling back to default.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater
...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar", zip file "/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/lib/x86, /data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

Предполагаю что ошибка связана с этим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делал:
1. Clean Project -> Rebuild
2. менял supportVersion на 27.0.2
3. Invalidate caches and restart
4. удалял папку libraries (.idea/libraries)
5. добавлял строку в proguard

```
-keep class android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater{ <init>(...); }
```

6. с бубном танцевал, магические слова говорил

Gradle: 4.6
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

android studio 3.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось что ошибка была из за того что я не интегрировал google API
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Answer (score 3):

Просто хочет, чтобы все версии библиотек `android.support` были под одну гребёнку (без миксов).

На уровне `Project` -> откройте папку `.idea` -> потом папку `libraries`, как показано на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На основе этих данных, посмотрите все ли либы используют одну и туже версию (и так понятно что не все, коль ошибка выскачила, но именно так можно узнать какие именно библиотеки выпендриваются).

Потом в `build.gradle` на уровне приложения добавляйте те либы, которые выпендрились.

> Например, если вы используете версию 28.0.0, а где-то в списке будет
>   либа с 27.0.2, то эту либу в грэдле и пропишите с последней версией.

*P.S.* Когда у меня такая ситуация была, то помимо основной `appcompact-v7` пришлось явно указать последнюю версию ещё для `palete-v7` и прочих суппортов:

```
ext.supportLibraryVersion = '28.0.0'

//#####################################################################
//  Don't delete.
//#####################################################################
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:$supportLibraryVersion"
//#####################################################################
```

---

А по поводу ошибки. Попробуйте добавить в `proguard-rules.pro` следующее:

```
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

или

```
-keep class android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater{ <init>(...); }
```

Comment: да действительно был 1 файл который отличался версией, ошибка в ide пропала, а вот ошибка в приложении нет...

Comment: @AstendSanferion обновил ответ.

Comment: добавление новых зависимостей и добавление указанных строчек в progurad не решило проблему, но в любом случае признателен за помощь. Поиски данной ошибки в интернете также не увенчались успехом, наверное буду писать в гугл)